# Php file download through ajax request

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to download file through ajax request.
I have below code in my php file to dowload

```
$filedata="File data here"
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment; filename=report.txt");
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
echo $filedata;
```

It giving me ajax response but not providing file download dialog box. Is any solution?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think ajax is blocking the request.

Since its ajax that reads from the server it might not trigger the file save dialog.

Comment: yes. It not trigger save dialog. Is any other solution to show save dialog box?

Comment: Don't use an AJAX request. Just do a `document.location` pointing at the url directly (for GET requests) or build a hidden form and submit that for POST requests.

Comment: Or for file down load, just add a link. If the browser get a content.Attachement it will not change page usually but only download the file and save it, staying on the current page. ANd if you want to be certain, add target="_BLANK" to the a tag and it will download in a new browser window.