# PHP file download: PHP is sending file data in ajax response but file is not downloading

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a `HTML` page that allows user to download the file there's a button to download it, I'm using an `onClick` event to make an `ajax` call to a `php` script that gives the file data.

The problem is the file data is being recieved in the response but file is not dowloading.

I've already referred to this [Php file download through ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052608/php-file-download-through-ajax-request) post but is not solving my problem

`HTML` page

```html
<button onClick="download()"> Download </button>

<script>
    function download {
    var url = "download"; //it is a code ignitor project hence it is just an action call.
    var path ="<?php echo $data[0]->file_path . $data[0]->file_name; ?>";
    $.post(url, {path: path}, function(result){

    });
</script>
```

`PHP script`

```php
public function download() {
        $path = $this->input->post('path');

        if(!file_exists($path)){
            die('file not found');
        } else {

            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($path) . "");
            header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
            readfile($path);
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: An AJAX response doesn't trigger a download.

Comment: There's no solution given in the question you linked to, so how did you expect it to help?

Comment: short answer, it doesn't work like that. there's no benefit using ajax here at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the server function so it uses a `get` parameter. Then open a new window with the script URL.

```
function download() {
    var path ="<?php echo $data[0]->file_path . $data[0]->file_name; ?>";
    var url = "download?path=" + encodeURIComponent(path); //it is a code ignitor project hence it is just an action call.
    window.open(url);
});
```

```
public function download() {
    $path = $this->input->get('path');

    if(!file_exists($path)){
        die('file not found');
    } else {
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($path) . "");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($path));
        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream;");
        readfile($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: This solves my problem. But I have two questions **How does the opened page closes automatically?** and **Is it safe to send the path through a `get` where it will be visible in the address bar of the browser?**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page for other solutions.

Comment: _“How does the opened page closes automatically?”_ - don’t open it in the first place. Use `location.href = …` instead of window.open - all modern browsers should _not_ replace the current document, if the response to the new request is one that triggers a download dialog. _“Is it safe to send the path through a get where it will be visible in the address bar of the browser?”_ - that depends on what you want it to be safe _against_ …